# How can I get info about hidden interacionts in chrome network tab?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm interested in see how the Aviator casino game works, I took a look to the network tab to figure out which interactions is performing my browser with the webserver but it is not showing any requests, I noticed that at the bottom of the network tab it says like 0/649 requests so, how can I get information about those 649 requests, are they hidden? how this game works?
this is the game https://spribe.co/games/aviator

[image: Network tab of the webpage]

Answer (score 0):

you might not able to see it in a browser but it uses a websocket with encrypted response back to client.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).